# Error : duplicate files during packaging of APK

Tags: android, duplicates, apk

I try to run an android eclipse on Android Studio.

I try many solutions on the internet.

But something wrong still happens

```html
Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK /home/sam/pst-adnew/panstage/build/outputs/apk/panstage-debug-unaligned.apk
 Path in archive: lib/armeabi-v7a/libmp3lame.so
 Origin 1: /home/sam/pst-adnew/panstage/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/pst-adnew/panstage_local_library/unspecified/jni/armeabi-v7a/libmp3lame.so
 Origin 2: /home/sam/pst-adnew/panstage/build/intermediates/ndk/debug/lib/armeabi-v7a/libmp3lame.so
You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
 android {
   packagingOptions {
     exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libmp3lame.so'
   }
 }
Error:Execution failed for task ':panstage:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK lib/armeabi-v7a/libmp3lame.so
   File 1: /home/sam/pst-adnew/panstage/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/pst-adnew/panstage_local_library/unspecified/jni/armeabi-v7a/libmp3lame.so
   File 2: /home/sam/pst-adnew/panstage/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/pst-adnew/panstage_local_library/unspecified/jni/armeabi-v7a/libmp3lame.so
```

I am working with NDK android studio..

Please help me.

I also tried the solution

```html
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
```

But it does not work anymore. Please help me :(

Comment: is this app as a dependency from another app?

Comment: i encounter this problem when i use third library. i solve by remove `.so` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libmp3lame.so'` as well in the  **PackagingOption** section.

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libmp3lame.so'

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, actually i tried it, but it doesn't help. Maybe another way

Answer (score 12):

In case of duplicate libraries (*.so) files, exclude option will not help as we cannot completely exclude the native binaries. There is one more option in packagingOptions. It is 'pickFirst'. We can avoid duplicate files error and include the first one the compiler encounters.

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libmp3lame.so'

    }
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I just spent kind of a long time trying to get compile.exclude to work for the aar file itself before coming across your answer. I was not familiar with pickFirst.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the reason was that a module was included twice in the long gradle file and hard to notice.

```
.
.
.
compile project(path: ':common', configuration: 'debug')
.
.
.
compile project(path: ':common')
.
.
.
```

So once it was adding the files in the debug folder and second time in the release folder.

Once caught, I removed the second line, since we needed everything in the debug version. Error went away.